# Negation error in 16 bit 2's complement code

Tags: c, math

It's a code for finding 2's complement. When `num` is `char`, it works fine for 8 bit. But when it is `unsigned int` for 16-bits numbers. Code doesn't work.
Can you guide?

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define ISNEGATIVE(num)     num & 0x80
#define TWO_COMP(num)       (~num) + 1

int main()
{
    unsigned int num;
    num = 0xFFFF;
    if(ISNEGATIVE(num))
        printf("1's = %d, 2's = %d", ~num, TWO_COMP(num));
    return 0;
}
```

Output :

> 1's = -65536, 2's = -65535

Comment: For 16-bit, `ISNEGATIVE` should use `0x8000`.

Comment: Yes I used that.. but still no use

Comment: There really is no good reason for a down-vote at this point IMO.  Problem statement is clear, effort is shown.  Its just a question from someone learning bit-wise methods.  But one suggestion for post is remove link to picture and edit the post to include `output` content at bottom.

Comment: 0xff unsigned value  is not negative in  int16_t format.

Comment: Edited that and also please check image

Comment: Please do _not_ change the content that defines your original question.  It makes any effort to assist circular, and confuses content in comments to new viewers.  Its okay to remove the link to the image, but please role back the edit that changes `0x80` to `0x8000`.

Comment: What output were you expecting?

Comment: is `unsigned int` on your system 16-bits?  I usually see it as 32 or 64 bit.  Then your ~ command is flipping a lot more bits than you expect causing "fun"  Use a 16-bit sized variable and I think you will get better results.  `uint16_t` I believe.

Comment: `%d` printf format specifier requires a parameter of type `int` (after default argument promotions), but you are using a parameter of type `unsigned int`.

Comment: Edited to roll 0x8000 back to its original 0x80 and the modified image showing the same non-original value to remove confusion in comments already rendered addressing this key issue.

Comment: @Ajinkya6174 - Please do not keep changing the ***original*** value `0x80` back to `0x8000`  This is the _central issue that you asked about_. When you change the original question, it confuses all of the comments and answers  that addressed that question in its original form .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `unsigned int` is a 32-bit variable on most computers. If you want to use a 16-bit value use `uint16_t` by preference, or `unsigned short`. You also need to use the appropriate half-word specifiers in your `printf` call:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define ISNEGATIVE(num)     num & 0x8000
#define TWO_COMP(num)       (~num) + 1

int main()
{
    /*unsigned short num;*/
    uint16_t num;
    num = 0xFFFF;
    if(ISNEGATIVE(num))
        printf("1's = %hd, 2's = %hd", ~num, TWO_COMP(num));
    return 0;
}
```

This outputs

```
1's = 0, 2's = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The 2 primary issues are:

- the width of the mask needs to match the width of the number being looked at:
- this algorithm should be limited to testing `signed` types,

Width of `char` AKA `int8_t` is 8 bits, so `0x80` works fine.
Width of `short int`  AKA `int16_t` is 16 bits so requires `0x8000`
Width of `int` AKA `int32_t` is 32 bits so would require `0x80000000`
and so on...

Because `num` in your code is 16 bits wide, the line:

```
#define ISNEGATIVE(num)     num & 0x80
```

Should be:

```
#define ISNEGATIVE(num)     num & 0x8000
```

Just as important, because the value stored in the MSB of an `unsigned` type does not make the value negative, the algorithm should only be used to evaluate `signed` types.

```
unsigned int num;
```

Should be:

```
int num;
```

Comment: The real problem with using `unsigned int` is that the value won't be sign-extended into the high-order 16 bits of the variable when a 16-bit negative quantity is loaded into it.

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica -  I do not disagree, but the other real problem here is that OP is expecting that after evaluating an `unsigned` value, that it will indeed be negative.  It is a fundamentally wrong assumption.  The algorithm, as written, is not intended to be (or at least shouldn't be) used with `unsigned` variables.  I was about to make this comment under your post, but thought I would just address it here. :)